# Avoiding Type I error in multipe t-tests of different groups of data

Tags: t-test

I am testing for difference several different groups, i.e.

> **A** vs **B**
>
> **C** vs **D**

Is it okay to run multiple t-test, one for each couple, since no group is tested twice?

Thank you *very very* much,

[EDIT]

A, B, C, D are different conditions of the same experiment, i.e.

```
A - performance of users with device A

B - performance of users with device B

C - performance of users with device C

D - performance of users with device D
```

and I want to test A vs B, and C vs D.
The experiment consist in using four different devices to fulfill a given teleoperation task.

Each user (20) perform experiment with all the conditions (devices) A,B,C,D, etc.

So I have a matrix of performances 20(users) x 4 (conditions) and I want to test 
A (column 1) vs B (column 2), and C (column 3) vs D (column 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the probability of a Type I error you need to correct. The tests do seem to be independent from your description, so the correct method would be to use Šidák correction. This is an exact adjustment under the condition of independence. It is based on the fact that in this case

$$\alpha = 1 - (1-\beta)^n$$
where $\beta$ is your significance niveau for your individual tests, $\alpha$ your Familywise Error Rate (FWER) and n the number of the independent tests. Solving this leads to the adjustment
$$
\beta=1-(1-\alpha)^\frac{1}{n}. 
$$
In your example this means with two tests you need to set your significance niveau to about $0.2532$ to have $\alpha=.05$. So not much better than Bonferroni in this case.

Much can be said about where and when the familywise control of Type I errors makes sense. In many cases Type I errors are introduced against by publication bias, but this is hard for an author to defend against.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons to adjust for multiple comparisons, and many things to consider (e.g., number of analyses, if you have a priori expectations, if you are using same or different groups, using same or different dependent variable). That being said, my intuition is that it is fine to run these t-tests without correcting for Type 1 error. Presumably these groups are independent and the tests are testing different hypotheses. Others are welcome to correct me!

Comment: Can you please describe your experiment more fully? It seems as if perhaps your conditions/groups are much more similar than I anticipated based on your original post.

Comment: I have described the experiment in detail. Thanks!!